# Flex: One data model, multiple platforms different UI, how to?

Tags: apache-flex

I have designed "the core" of the application i am working on ( it communication with the server, data processing, etc. ), and now i am a bit stuck on the User Interface, because i wish it to be specific, and probably different on the different platforms it goin to run on ( PC, tablet, gsm ).

My question basically is :

- How to separate the "core" of the application, which must remain the same for all of the platforms, from the UI's which shall be very different applications ?

// question is about Flash Builder 4.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a "Flex Library Project" which contains your core application logic, services, data model, etc. This will ultimately compile into a SWC file which is a generic-purpose library for a Flash or Flex project.  Then create a distinct Flex Project for each user interface you'd like to build and declare a dependency on the Flex Library Project you created.

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=projects_7.html

Comment: could it be used without compiling into SWC ?

Comment: If you are using Flash Builder (or another IDE) you just need to add the library project as dependency of the other projects. It will take care of compiling the SWC for you and make it available to the other projects.

Comment: i see. ok. i will read further on the topic, since i got the idea now.

Comment: I added a link that should give you most of the info you need if you're using Flash Builder.

Comment: You don't have to use the library if you don't want to (however, I do recommend it).  As an alternative, you can always 'add source' from the other project in the current project (/LibraryProjectName/srcFolder/) and it will compile it all every time, but then it won't be as portable/clean, and would mean that recompiling your project would take longer.